# How can I align my 2 texts on the same row?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve something simple and the rules make it non-trivial. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/ynrmwgt9/). It is non-trivial for me to align the elements in a natural way, I think the elements should be on the same row when I make a `float:left`.

Comment: Instead of using h1 (or block level elements that add a newline), use inline elements or add dedicated styling for block level elements to make them inline.

Answer (score 3):

`Hx` elements have default margins.

The "space" from the top cause by the `margin-top` property of the H1 element.
Consider using a `reset.css` file to reset those default values.
Another thing is the `line-height` property.

**In conclusion:**

- `margin-top:0;`
- `line-height: 20px;` (choose a value that fits to your needs)

http://jsfiddle.net/ynrmwgt9/4/

Comment: Oh.. Didn't know that `hx` had some properties like this ! My answer's working, but yours maybe more appropriate to the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to wrap your `div` in a **container div**. A little bit like *bootstrap* system.

See the fiddle, and ask me if you have questions about :)

I'm using something like this :

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>Content 1</div>
    <div class='col'>Content 2</div>
</div>
```

The stylesheet has to specify that `row`fill 100% of the width, and your two columns, the half, then 50% each.

```
.row
{
    width:100%;
}

.col
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}
```

*Text align center is just for make it beautiful*

http://jsfiddle.net/ynrmwgt9/2/